# How do I search a NTEXT column for XML attributes and update the values? MS SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

**Duplicate:** this exact question was asked by the same author in [How do I update a XML string in an ntext column in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221583/how-do-i-update-a-xml-string-in-an-ntext-column-in-sql-server). Please close this one and answer in the original question.

---

I have a SQL table with 2 columns. ID(int) and Value(ntext)

The value rows have all sorts of xml strings in them.

```
ID   Value
--   ------------------
1    <ROOT><Type current="TypeA"/></ROOT>
2    <XML><Name current="MyName"/><XML>
3    <TYPE><Colour current="Yellow"/><TYPE>
4    <TYPE><Colour current="Yellow" Size="Large"/><TYPE>
5    <TYPE><Colour current="Blue" Size="Large"/><TYPE>
6    <XML><Name current="Yellow"/><XML>
```

How do I:

```
   A. List the rows where <TYPE><Colour current="Yellow",
    bearing in mind that there is an entry
    <XML><Name current="Yellow"/><XML>


   B. Modify the rows that contain
    <TYPE><Colour current="Yellow" to be
    <TYPE><Colour current="Purple"
```

Thanks! 4 your help

Comment: Typically, you would use the XML data type for this, not NTEXT. Are you able to change the database schema?

Comment: Exact duplicate by same author: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221583/how-do-i-update-a-xml-string-in-an-ntext-column-in-sql-server

Comment: I cant update the column

Comment: You could have updated your other question instead of creating a duplicate....

Comment: Ok, sorry Im new to the site. I have just registered and will do that next time.

Comment: @Alan: I updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use UPDATETEXT, TEXTPTR and PATINDEX, [this article](http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2008/05/03/3417.aspx) gives a nice SearchAndReplace sproc.